# How to call a function everytime on iteration in LWC?

Tags: lightning, javascript, lightning-web-components

This is my code:

```
//myComponent.html
<template for:each={myData} for:item="status">

  // Do something

</template>

//myComponent.js
changeColor(){

  // Do something

}
```

I want to call `changeColor` everytime on iteration for each 'status' item. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If this function returns something then we can just put that in the list or something.Which we can iterate over and achieve the end result. Or if still you need to call a function try
putting it with the events(function is of js) such as using onchange/onclick sort of attributes withing the tags like button/input etc. in the template iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer is "you can't" but there are two alternatives:

- precompute values in the list as Chetan suggested. When you load your data, loop in JS and call your function for each list item and save the result in an attribute of your list item. You can then use those values in the markup under the iteration.
- embed that logic in a child component that you place in your iteration. The child component can call its own function when it's rendered.