# Retrieving field value in nested for loop

Tags: lightning-web-components

I'm trying to build a table by looping on the fieldset and a list of contacts here's the code:

```
<template>
    <table class="slds-table slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_bordered">
        <thead>
            <template for:each={fieldSetData.data} for:item="field">
                <tr key={field.apiName} class="slds-line-height_reset">
                    <th class="" data-scope="col">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title="">{field.Label}</div>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </template>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <template for:each={fieldSetData.data} for:item="field">
                <template for:each={contacts.data} for:item="data">
                    <tr key={data.Id} class="slds-hint-parent">
                        <td data-label="Name" data-scope="row">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title={data[field.Name]}>{data[field.Name]}</div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </template>
            </template>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</template>
```

Here's the error message:

> Invalid expression {data[field.Name]} - LWC1038: Template expression
>   doesn't allow computed property access

I'm assuming you can't retrieve data using that expression. What are the other ways I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert your objects into lists. The following code should suffice:

```
let fields = [...,]; // the list of field names
let rows = [{...},]; // the list of objects/records
let output = rows.map(row => ({id: row.Id, data: fields.map(field => row[field])}));
```

At this point, your data now looks like:

```
[ [ "Id1", "First1", "Last1", "Phone1" ],
  [ "Id2", "First2", "Last2", "Phone2" ] ]
```

So your template simply becomes:

```
        <template for:each={records} for:item="record">
            <template for:each={record.data} for:item="data">
                <tr key={record.id} class="slds-hint-parent">
                    <td data-label="Name" data-scope="row">
                        <div class="slds-truncate" title={data}>{data}</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </template>
        </template>
```

*(Note: this may require some tweaking to get the layout correct.)*

Comment: This is probably not in the scope of this question but, is there a way to combine the 2 lists such that the output would be `"data": [
            [
                {
                FieldName : "Name",
                Value : "Joe",
                type : "Text"
                },
                {
                    FieldName : "Phone",
                    Value : "123455678",
                    type : "Phone"
                }
            ]
        ]`

Answer (score 0):

You can't write JavaScript in expressions like `data[field.Name]`. The expression engine only supports child object access with `.` and not array access.

See alternatives in my answer here: [How to call a function everytime on iteration in LWC?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/294330/how-to-call-a-function-everytime-on-iteration-in-lwc)

Comment: It's still a problem because I still won't know what to loop on to build the table. Since users can remove/add fields in the fieldset. unless I have a {value:'', key:''} which I populate using the fieldset and contacts. Well, this sucks.

Comment: You would have to go for option 2: split that component in two with a child component.